# Only 1 child after 5 forks (C)

Tags: c, process, fork, pid

I am trying to make a processor farm in C. I start with opening message queues, and afterwards try to make worker processes: (note that NROF_WORKERS is 5)

```
static void
makechildren (void) {
    // Only the parent should fork. Any children created will become workers. 
    pid_t   processID; 
    pid_t   farmerPID = getpid(); // To identify who the farmer is

    // Loop creating processes, indexed by NROF_WORKERS
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < NROF_WORKERS){
        if (getpid() == farmerPID){
            i++; 
            printf ("Parent is creating a child!%d\n", getpid()); 
            processID = fork();
        }
    }

    if (processID < 0){
        perror("fork() failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
    // If parent, start farming
        if (processID == farmerPID) {
            printf("Parent reporting in!%d\n");
        }
    // If child, become a worker
        if (processID == 0) {
            printf("Child reporting in!%d\n", getpid()); 
            join();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want the parent to report any time a child is created, and afterwards I want the parent and all children to report. However, this is all I get:

```
Parent is creating a child!11909
Parent is creating a child!11909
Parent is creating a child!11909
Parent is creating a child!11909
Parent is creating a child!11909
Child reporting in!11914
```

Now, I do notice the difference in 11909 and 11914 is 5. So my question: are the other processes created? If so, how come they don't report? And if not, what am I doing wrong? Also, the parent is not reporting at all, how is this caused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the children are created, but will loop forever in the `while` loop, as `i` is incremented only for the parent:

```
int i = 0; 
while (i < NROF_WORKERS){
    if (getpid() == farmerPID){    
        i++;             // <---- This is happening for the parent process only.
        printf ("Parent is creating a child!%d\n", getpid()); 
        processID = fork();
    }
}
```

The only child to terminate is the last one, for which the `i` is equal to `NROF_WORKERS`.

Also parent is "not reporting" since the `processID` you are checking to be equal to the parent PID is never equal to it, as it is equal to the latest `fork` result, i.e. the latest created child PID:

```
.........
 processID = fork();
.........
.........
 if (processID == farmerPID) {
            printf("Parent reporting in!%d\n");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You always print the `farmerPid`! But as the message is printed 5 times, you effectively created 5 processes:

```
while (i < NROF_WORKERS){
    if (getpid() == farmerPID){
        i++; 
        printf ("Parent is creating a child!%d\n", getpid()); 
        processID = fork();
    }
}
```

If you want to print the children pids then your code must makes a difference in between parent and child, as in:

```
while (i < NROF_WORKERS){
    if (getpid() == farmerPID){
        i++; 
        printf ("Parent is creating a child!\n"); 
        processID = fork();
        if (processID==0) { // child
            printf("I am the child %d\n",getpid());
        } else { // parent
            printf("Parent just created child %d\n",processID);
        }
    }
}
```